How can I run JaCoCo with gradle using Intellij?
I am getting the following error when trying to run a Spring Boot test with coverage in Intellij.
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader 'bootstrap' attempted duplicate class definition for java.lang.$JaCoCo. (java.lang.$JaCoCo is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')

I am using Intellij 2024.1.4 Ultimate, Java 17 Temurin, and Gradle 7.6. I've also switched the coverage runner to be Jacoco as shown in the screenshot below.

I am also using Jacoco 0.8.8, but I'm not explicitly stating the version from Gradle. I am instead, using the plugin as is as a part of the test stage.

apply plugin: 'jacoco'
...
test {
    jacoco {
        excludes = [
                'org/hibernate/**/*__$*$__*'
        ]
    }
    environment "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE", "test"
    useJUnitPlatform()
    finalizedBy jacocoTestReport // report is always generated after tests run
}

jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
        xml.enabled true
        html.enabled true
    }
}

If I remove the jacoco plugin from gradle, then it works because there isn't a duplicate JVM entry for jacoco (from Intellij and Gradle).
Is there a way for gradle to use jacoco from Intellij, or vice-versa? I want to be able to configure jacoco from gradle, but still view the coverage in the coverage window in intellij.
